# OData Automapper ProjectTo ExplicitExpansion Filter child EF

Tags: entity-framework, odata, automapper

I'm having trouble trying to implement OData with a custom DTO using Automapper's ProjectTo.

Lets say I have the following Objects:

```
public class Freight
{
   public virtual ICollection<General.Fleet.Service> Services { get; set; }
}

public class FreightDTO
{
   public virtual ICollection<DTO.General.Fleet.Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

AutomapperConfiguration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<General.Fleet.Freight, DTO.General.Fleet.FreightDTO>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Services, options => options.ExplicitExpansion())

cfg.CreateMap<DTO.General.Fleet.FreightDTO, General.Fleet.Freight>()
                    .ForMember(x => x.Services, options => options.ExplicitExpansion())
```

I'm trying to apply the OData filters through the ApplyTo method like so:

```
query.ApplyTo(db.Freight.ProjectTo<FreightDTO>()) as IQueryable<FreightDTO>;
```

But whenever I try to filter:

http://localhost:22564/api/Freights?$top=1&$filter=Services/any(s: contains(s/PrimaryCode, '41156') eq true)

I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'Services' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

For what I understand I'm failling to filter by a property that is not included in the Projection. But I'm trying to avoid this include, because I don't want to bring all the Child objects, just filter the parent based on them.

What I don't want to do:

```
query.ApplyTo(db.Freight.ProjectTo<FreightDTO>(null, "Services")) as IQueryable<FreightDTO>;
```

Since I'm using OData's ODataQueryOptions 'ApplyTo' I'm not able to previously apply the filters in the dataset passed to Automapper (to filter directly on the entity rather than the DTO).

So my question is: Is there a way to filter a parent object based on the child, without having to bring the childs from the database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Check if you are using the EnableQuery attribute on your controller. This appends the Where Linq clause post return. So if you have not included you'll get this error. Try removing the attribute.